# Saving post values in a session array

Tags: php, session, post

I want to save values send via POST in a session array:

```
$reply = array('thread_id', 'reply_content');

$_POST['thread_id'] = 2; # test it

$_SESSION['reply'] = array();



foreach ($reply as $key)
{
    if (in_array($key, $_POST))
    {
        $_SESSION['reply'][$key] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}

var_dump($_SESSION['reply']);
```

For example I want to check if the keys 'thread_id' and 'thread_content' are send in post, if they are then I want to save them in a session array called reply, using the same keys.

So for example if 'thread_id' is send via POST:

```
$_POST['thread_id'] = 'blah';
```

Then this should get saved in a session called 'reply', using the same key:

```
$_SESSION['reply']['thread_id'] = 'blah';
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Does the code you wrote not work? You're asking how to do it but your question includes the code to do it.

Comment: Just use save it as `$_SESSION['reply']['thread_id'] = $_POST['thread_id];`.

Comment: the code seems correct. Is the session initialized correctly?

Comment: session_start is there...I forgot to add it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
  $reply = array('thread_id', 'reply_content');

    $_POST['thread_id'] = 2; # test it

    $_SESSION['reply'] = array();
    foreach ($reply as $key)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$key]))
        {
            $_SESSION['reply'][$key] = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }
```

Comment: in_array will check for the values not for keys.

Answer (score 2):

In general, your approach looks valid, but I'm going to guess that you may not be calling [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start), which is necessary to persist session data.

```
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['POST']) $_SESSION['POST'] = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION['POST'][$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($_SESSION['POST']);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`in_array($needle, $haystack)`](http://php.net/in_array) checks whether `$needle` is a *value* in `$haystack` and not a key. Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) or [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) instead:

```
foreach ($reply as $key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_POST))
    {
        $_SESSION['reply'][$key] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}
```

Or:

```
$_SESSION['reply'] = array_merge($_SESSION['reply'], array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($reply)));
```